# Tensile pressure on a strap around a pool

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics

We have built a swimming pool out of pallets, with heavy duty ratchet straps around the outside, holding it in a circle.  The pool is $4'$ high and the circumference is $57'$ ($16'$ diameter).  The straps are $2''$ wide.

At the bottom of the pool, the outward pressure on the wall is $1.7 \,\text{psi}$.  How can I calculate the tensile stress put on the straps holding it together?

*I calculated the overall outward pressure on the straps to be $1.7 \times 2 \times ( 57 \times 12 ) = 2,326.5\,\text{lbs}$ but I'm not sure how to relate that to tensile stress*

Thank you!

Comment: This site has 17 questions on Ringworld. E.G. [Why is Larry Niven's Ringworld Unstable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41254/37364) [Calculating ringworld self-gravitation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421821/37364) But I didn't see one equivalent to this question.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/hoop-stress

Comment: Thank you, @mmesser314 - "hoop stress" appears to be the term I need.  But all the formulas for hoop stress include the thickness of the vessel wall.

Comment: I should add that I'm totally happy to make assumptions like the strap is directly holding the water (taking the pallets out of the equation.)